# Order items by option value

Tags: javascript, html

I've got the code below, the code is fine, the only issue is that if I did something wrong in order, and I would like to correct it, the whole text is gotten erased and started from the beginning:

```
function getValues() {
var result = [];
var me = this; 
$('select').each(function (idx, el) {
    var $el = $(el);
    result[3*$el.val()+idx]=($el.next('input[type="hidden"]').val() + ' ' + $el.val());
    if (me === el) return false;
});
console.log(result);
$('#res').html(result.join(' '));
}

$('select.startID,input[type="hidden"]').change(getValues);


<select name="startID[]" class="startID">
<option value="0">SELECT</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="startText[]" value="Text1">
Text1
<br />

<select name="startID[]" class="startID">
<option value="0">SELECT</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="startText[]" value="Text2">
Text2

<br />

<select name="startID[]" class="startID">
<option value="0">SELECT</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="startText[]" value="Text3">
Text3
<div id="res"></div>
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/aburayane/zwzx7ann/

So the text in front of select box is the same in hidden input, I should select the same value from select box that correspond to the text in front, for example 1 => Text1, 2 => Text2, 3 => Text3, if by mistake, I selected 1 => Text2, 2=> Text1 and 3=> Text3, so my mistakes are in Text1 and Text2, I did not select the correct values, if I would like to correct, the whole text is gotten erased and starting from the beginning.

My Question: Is there any method to make corrections on the text printed without erasing data, it should be swapped together.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing strange in here since you have mentionned to you `getValues` function to break once the current `select` element in the `each` loop is the one subject to change with:

```js
if (me === eq) return false;
```

So once you have choosen some value for all three `select` elements, you are back to the first one for example, the iteration will change the first element and check if it is the one subject to change event and `return false` which will abslolutelly prevent subsequent iterations, thus the following `select` element choices won't be shown even they was already choosen before.

What you need is a straightforward `function` that, don't only check if current `select` is the one that is being altered, but also to check if the next item was already present in the result string. This can be simply done by checking if latter value is already in the *res* html string, the condition then may be like so:

```js
if ((me === el) && !nextItemWasAlreadyShown(idx + 1)) 
  return false; //Check if next element (idx + 1) of the current select was already in the res string
```

Where the nextItemWasAlreadyShown function declaration looks like below:

```js
function nextItemWasAlreadyShown(index) {
  var continueLoop = false;
  var resText = $('#res').html();
  var text = $('select').eq(index).next('input[type="hidden"]').val();
  if (resText.indexOf(text) > -1) 
    continueLoop = true;
  return continueLoop;
}
```

**A full demonstration can be found in a modified version of your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zwzx7ann/1/).**

Comment: the above example is ordered by Text not by value

Comment: What do you mean? My snippet aimed to solve your basic need *"make corrections on the text printed without erasing data"*. Don't know what are you referring to in here.

Comment: if you select 3, then 2 then 1, the text shown is `Text1 3 Text2 2 Text3 1`, it is ordered by Text+Number, however I am looking for this order: `Text3 1 Text2 2 Text1 3`, it is ordered by value

Comment: This wan't mentionned in the OP, as the only problem was how to keep old data and do not erase it.

Comment: yes, I understand, but before adding your code, data is in order, so something messed up to get it unordered

Comment: You should have at least appreciated the effort and upvoted the answer, but you seem to be driving me to provide the whole answer...

Comment: sorry tmarwen, I do appreciate it, but I found that the code is not complete, so I am still waiting for assistance

Comment: I will try to provide a new version as son as i can but that being said, you have to work your own road and you will learn too much more tha having a ready made answer :)

Comment: thanks tmarwen, I could code simple ones, but I am still learning, so I learn from your codes